# Buildpacks: Is there any way to change the default location '/workspace' where all the source code gets copied during 'pack build' command

Tags: node.js, docker, buildpack

Buildpacks: Is there any way to change the default location '/workspace' where all the source code gets copied during 'pack build' command.
Referring to : https://buildpacks.io/

Example , this command "pack build sample-app --path samples/apps/java-maven --builder cnbs/sample-builder:bionic" will create a runnable image which will have '/workspace' location hosting all your app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't think this is possible as it looks like "workspace" is [hard coded](https://github.com/buildpacks/pack/blob/aa49ae6d845f40bd576cc488a3105845e9e77506/internal/build/mount_paths.go#L36) in the pack code.

However the Cloud Native Buildpacks lifecycle does allow the app directory to be specified, so maybe that is a feature that could be added.

Comment: thanks submitted the request : https://github.com/buildpacks/docs/issues/344